# How can I know the requiring module?

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I have module `A` that `require`s module `B`.  is it possible for `B` to know the identity of `A`?

Comment: Is this specifically for Node.js or all CommonJS environments?

Comment: I'd say that you can always include a parameter or a seperate method to pass the identity of A to B

Comment: @PatrickRoberts just node.js for now

Comment: Yes it is possible but it's a bit of a hack and makes the assumption that [`require.cache`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) is never tampered with by other modules, which is not always a safe assumption to make.